# Magento-change default value of select field in admin

Tags: magento, configuration, admin

i want to change the default value of a field in my admin panel. 
an example of app/code/core/mage/page/etc/config.xml

```
<default>
 <design>
     <head translate="default_description" module="page">
         <default_title>Magento Commerce</default_title>
         <default_description>Default Description</default_description>
         <default_keywords>Magento, Varien, E-commerce</default_keywords>
         <default_robots>*</default_robots>
         <default_media_type>text/html</default_media_type>
         <default_charset>utf-8</default_charset>
         <default_demonotice>1</default_demonotice><!--for example change this default value-->
     </head>
     <header translate="welcome" module="page">
         <logo_src>images/logo.gif</logo_src>
         <logo_alt>Magento Commerce</logo_alt>
         <welcome>Default welcome msg!</welcome>
     </header>
     <footer translate="copyright" module="page">
         <copyright>&amp;copy; 2008 Magento Demo Store. All Rights Reserved.</copyright>
     </footer>
 </design>
```

help please!

Comment: do you want to make change to this config.xml file or in your own module somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in system.xml files for the path

and in order to overwrite the value do

```
<default>
    <module><set><field>some_value</field></set></module>
</default>
```